# Oracle PL/SQL : report formatting

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have been asked to create a report using PL/SQL to get names associated with a given city. While this is not in the least bit difficult, I find that the way in which the data is to be presented is something I have not seen from SQL. The report needs to be formatted such that the city name appears first and all subsequent people associated with that city are to be listed after that - in a single line.

```
TEMPE: Rich Allen, Jerry Black, et al..
TUSCON: Bob Adams, Frank Bruce, et al..
```

I can't recall ever seeing output like this and am a bit stuck on how to present this data.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: use wmconcat on the name.

Comment: Why do you need a stored procedure?

Answer (score 1):

```
Select city, wmConcat(namefield)
from tablename
group by City
```

WM_CONCAT for versions 10g and prior
LISTAGG for newer versions.